# Map authorization resource URIs to RPT token in Keycloak

Tags: keycloak

Is it possible to map the `Client => Authorization => Resources => {Resource} => URIs` to the RPT token? This way, access to a resource could be checked based on token and without any additional request to Keycloak.

[image]

Excpected (partial) token

```
{
  "aud": "shop",
  "preferred_username": "bob",
  ...
  "authorization": {
    "permissions": [
      ...
      {
        "scopes": [
          "Read",
          "Manage"
        ],
        "rsid": "a7ff18e5-fc31-4a3f-8c0e-4e2ea2943f41",
        "rsname": "Articles"
        // I'd like to see the URIs here
        // "uris": [ "/api/v1/Article/*" ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```